# mysql "and" logic within result set

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements, resultset, logical-operators

Say I have a data set like the following:

```
table foo

id | employeeType | employeeID
-------------------------
 1 | Developer    | 1
 2 | Developer    | 2
 3 | Developer    | 3
 4 | Manager      | 1
 5 | Manager      | 4
 6 | Manager      | 5
 7 | CEO          | 1
 8 | CEO          | 6
```

and I wanted to run a query that would return all the employeeids (along with the employeeTypes) where there is a common employee id between all employeeTypes (that's the 'and' logic.  ONly employeeIDs that have all employeeTypes will return.  employeeType = Developer and employeeType=Manager and employeeType=CEO).  For the data above the example output would be

```
result table

id | employeeType | employeeID
-------------------------
 1 | Developer    | 1
 4 | Manager      | 1
 7 | CEO          | 1
```

I was able to do this when I only had only TWO employeeTypes by self joining the table like this.

```
select * from foo as fooOne
join foo as fooTwo
on fooOne.employeeID = fooTwo.employeeID
AND
fooOne.employeeType <> fooTwo.employeeType
```

that query returns a result set with values from fooTwo when the 'and' logic matches, but again, only for two types of employees.  My real use case scenario dictates that I need to be able to handle a variable number of employeeTypes (3, 4, 5, etc...)

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return the rows that you want:

```
SELECT foo.*
FROM
  foo
WHERE
  employeeID IN (
    SELECT employeeID
    FROM foo
    GROUP BY employeeID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT employeeType) =
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employeeType)
       FROM foo)
  )
```

Please see a [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f65d/1).

The inner query will return the number of distinct employee types:

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employeeType) FROM foo)
```

The middle query will return all the employee IDs that have the maximum number of employee types:

```
SELECT employeeID
FROM foo
GROUP BY employeeID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT employeeType) =
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employeeType) FROM foo)
```

and the outer query will return the whole rows.

Comment: Wow!  Works great.  Thanks a lot and the fiddle is also above and beyond.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this might be looked down as a very inefficient/hacky way of doing things, but this should still get the job done. And frankly, I can't see any other way out of this.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EmployeeType ORDER BY EmployeeType) AS Roles 
  FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID
) EMPLOYEE_ROLES
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ROLES.Roles = 'CEO,Developer,Manager';
```

Note that the comma separated list of roles provided in the end is in the alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a subquery to make it dynamic

```
SELECT employeeID, employeeType
FROM foo
WHERE employeeID IN (
SELECT  employeeID
FROM foo
GROUP BY employeeID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT employeeType) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employeeType) FROM foo)
)
```

Comment: ah yes... that makes perfect sense.  Thank you!